# Xml: ошибка not well formed

Tags: php, post

При отправке `xml` строки в ответ получаю в ответ от `api`: `Error parsing XML: not well formed;`

Cсылка на [документацию](https://api.privatbank.ua/rest-fiz.html).

Используя для отправки запроса `ajax`, все ок. Но мне это не подходит.

```
$url = "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/rest_fiz";       
$xml2='
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <request version="1.0">        
     <merchant>
       <id>75482</id>
       <signature>5abf5c7524bc2a835acb3a9e24ce10bc5ba82a99</signature>
     </merchant>
     <data>
    <oper>cmt</oper>
    <wait>0</wait>
    <test>0</test>
        <payment id="">
          <prop name="sd" value="11.08.2013" />
          <prop name="ed" value="11.09.2013" />
          <prop name="card" value="5168742060221193" />
        </payment>
      </data>
    </request>';
$stream_options = array (
        'http' => array (
                'method' => "POST",
                'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                'content' => $xml2
        )
        );
        $context=stream_context_create($stream_options);
        $response=file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
        $array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Кто-то ещё плюсует такие вопросы, всё же ясно - xml у вас неправильного формата, так как начинается с `\n` - переноса строки. Создайте отдельный файл для xml запроса, к примеру, request.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<request version="1.0">        
 <merchant>
   <id>75482</id>
   <signature>5abf5c7524bc2a835acb3a9e24ce10bc5ba82a99</signature>
 </merchant>
 <data>
<oper>cmt</oper>
<wait>0</wait>
<test>0</test>
    <payment id="">
      <prop name="sd" value="11.08.2013" />
      <prop name="ed" value="11.09.2013" />
      <prop name="card" value="5168742060221193" />
    </payment>
  </data>
</request>
```

далее через `file_get_contents()` получаем его:

```
$url = "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/rest_fiz";       
$xml2= file_get_contents('request.xml'); 
$stream_options = array (
             'http' => array (
                   'method' => "POST",
                   'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
                   'content' => $xml2
                 )
             );
$context=stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response=file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)), true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = "https://api.privatbank.ua/p24api/rest_fiz";
$id = 123456;
$password = 'tralalatralalatralala';//который из 32-х букавак

$data = '<oper>cmt</oper><wait>0</wait><test>0</test><payment id=""><prop name="sd" value="01.06.2018" /><prop name="ed" value="30.07.2018" /><prop name="card" value="1111222233334444" /></payment>';

$sign=sha1(md5($data.$password));

$xml_form = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><request version="1.0"><merchant><id>'.$id.'</id><signature>'.$sign.'</signature></merchant><data>'.$data.'</data></request>';
$stream_options = array (
    'http' => array (
        'method' => "POST",
        'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'content' => $xml_form
    )
);
$context=stream_context_create($stream_options);
$response=file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
$array_data = json_decode(json_encode(simplexml_load_string($response)), true);
print_r($array_data);
```